# Euler discretization of the O.D.E. Newton method yield the standard Newton method

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods, nonlinear-optimization

Under what conditions will an Euler discretization of the O.D.E. Newton method yield the standard Newton method for optimization?

Thank you